# Equivalent Syntax of Neo4j Query in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

This is one of the query that works fine in Neo4j Browser but when converting into an equivalent .Net query throws exception
The Cypher Query is

```
Match (c:Template)-[r1:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG1]->(dim1:Natural_Account),
        (c)-[r2:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG2]->(dim2:Legal_Entity_123),
        (c)-[r3:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG3]->(dim3:ICSegment), 
        (c)-[r4:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG4]->(dim4:Department_123), 
        (c)-[r5:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG5]->(dim5:Project_123),
        (b:Template) <-[r6:DEPENDS_ON]-(c)
        where dim1.Id in [-1,277] AND dim2.Id in [-1,115] AND dim3.Id in [103,-1] AND dim4.Id in [101,-1] AND dim5.Id in [-1,102] and 
        b.Id = 227 and b.ScenarioId = 200 and c.ScenarioId = 200
        with collect(DISTINCT(r1.LineIds)) as L1, collect(DISTINCT(r2.LineIds)) as L2,collect(DISTINCT(r3.LineIds)) as L3, collect(DISTINCT(r4.LineIds)) as L4, collect(DISTINCT(r5.LineIds)) as L5, collect(DISTINCT(r6.LineIds)) as L6 
        With REDUCE(output = [], r IN L1 | output + r) AS l1, REDUCE(output = [], r IN L2 | output + r) AS l2,REDUCE(output = [], r IN L3 | output + r) AS l3,REDUCE(output = [], r IN L4 | output + r) AS l4
        ,REDUCE(output = [], r IN L5 | output + r) AS l5
        ,REDUCE(output = [], r IN L6 | output + r) AS l6
        where size(filter(x in l1 where x in l2 and x in l3 and x in l4 and x in l5 and x in l6))>0
        return c
```

The equivalent query in .Net is as follows :

```
 var match = @"(c:Template)-[r1:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG1]->(dim1:Natural_Account),
(c)-[r2:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG2]->(dim2:Legal_Entity_123),
(c)-[r3:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG3]->(dim3:ICSegment), 
(c)-[r4:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG4]->(dim4:Department_123), 
(c)-[r5:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG5]->(dim5:Project_123),
(b:Template) <-[r6:DEPENDS_ON]-(c)";
var query = client.Cypher
                        .Match(match)
                        .Where("dim1.Id in [277,1]")
                        .AndWhere("dim2.Id in [115,1]")
                        .AndWhere("dim3.Id in [102,1]")
                        .AndWhere("dim4.Id in [101,1]")
                        .AndWhere("dim5.Id in [101,1]")
                        .AndWhere("b.Id = 227 and b.ScenarioId = 200")
                        .AndWhere("c.ScenarioId = 200")
                        .With("collect(DISTINCT(r1.LineIds)) as L1, collect(DISTINCT(r2.LineIds)) as L2,collect(DISTINCT(r3.LineIds)) as L3, collect(DISTINCT(r4.LineIds)) as L4, collect(DISTINCT(r5.LineIds)) as L5, collect(DISTINCT(r6.LineIds)) as L6,c")
                       .With("REDUCE(output = [], r IN L1 | output + r) AS l1, REDUCE(output = [], r IN L2 | output + r) AS l2,REDUCE(output = [], r IN L3 | output + r) AS l3,REDUCE(output = [], r IN L4 | output + r) AS l4, REDUCE(output = [], r IN L5 | output + r) AS l5, REDUCE(output = [], r IN L6 | output + r) AS l6, c")
                       .AndWhere("size(filter(x in l1 where x in l2 and x in l3 and x in l4 and x in l5 and x in l6))>0")
                       .ReturnDistinct((c) => c.As<Template>()).Results;
```

This seems to have some problem in syntax. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the fix.

```
.AndWhere("size(filter(x in l1 where x in l2 and x in l3 and x in l4 and x in l5 and x in l6))>0")
```

needs to be changed to

```
.Where("size(filter(x in l1 where x in l2 and x in l3 and x in l4 and x in l5 and x in l6))>0")
```

Since, I have just one Where condition at the end, using AndWhere() is creating problem.